# MPDF и кириллица

Tags: mpdf, php, кириллица, pdf

Подскажите как работать с библиотекой mPDF для вывода текста в кириллице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло php_value mbstring.func_overload = 0 
Установить значение пришлось в php.ini

mPDF работает намного быстрее, чем TCPDF

Answer (score 0):

Создайте файл index.php в той же папке, что и mpdf.php
Заполните его следующим образом:

```
<?php
$html = '
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Русский текст</td>
        <td>Русский текст</td>
        <td>Русский текст</td>
        <td>Русский текст</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Русский текст</td>
        <td>Русский текст</td>
        <td>Русский текст</td>
        <td><a href="http://mpdf.bpm1.com/" title="mPDF">mPDF</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>';

include("mpdf.php");
//Кодировка | Формат | Размер шрифта | Шрифт
//Отступы: слева | справа | сверху | снизу | шапка | подвал
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4', '10', 'Arial', 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5);
$mpdf->charset_in = 'utf-8';

$stylesheet = 'table {
                    text-align: center;
                    width: 320px;
                    color: #ff44ee;
                    margin: 0;
                    float: left;
               }
               td {
                    width: 80px;
               }';

//Записываем стили
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;
//Записываем html
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
$mpdf->Output('mpdf.pdf', 'I');
```

**Обратите внимание, что я привел пример для файла в кодировке utf-8!

Если нужна другая кодировка (например cp-1251), не забудьте исправить ее и в файле!**
Пример взят [habrahabr](http://habrahabr.ru/post/111979/) и доработан для наглядности.

Comment: Загуглить я и сам могу.   
При данных настроек выводится пустой документ. Точнее белый фон с белыми буквами.   
А при   
$mpdf = new new mPDF('c');   
текст выводится нормально, но кириллица выводится знаками вопроса.

Comment: Предоставьте тогда больше информации. Какая версия mPDF? Какая кодировка файла? Приведите пример кода, который у вас не работает. К сожалению, я не телепат, и угадать, что именно у вас не так я не могу. Был задан вопрос - я на него ответил, предварительно **проверив** работоспособность примера на версии mPDF 5.7. Указанный мной пример работает идеально.

Comment: Версия последняя. Проблем с кодом нет. Скорее всего проблема с настройками сервера.   
Сейчас установлено:   
php_value mbstring.func_overload 2   
php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8

Comment: Вы все-таки добавьте пример кода, в котором вы формируете выходной PDF. Я проверю этот код на своем окружении. Убедиться, что код работает, вы можете по этой ссылке: http://domencost.owebs.ru/MPDF57/index.php

Comment: Для примера example29_multilingual_autofont.php возникает ошибка:   
Warning: unpack(): Type n: not enough input, need 2, have 0

Comment: У вас не работает стандартный пример? У меня он работает идеально. Если же вы модифицировали стандартный пример, мы будем до бесконечности гадать, что же у вас не так, не видя ваш код. Единственное, что мне приходит в голову, что у вас в php.ini стоит magic_quotes_gpc = On. Если да, измените значение на Off и проверьте пример еще раз.

Comment: Вы же сами написали что у вас перегружены string функции в php_value mbstring.func_overload 2  вот поставьте 0 или 7. Или пользуйтесь TCPDF

Comment: Вышеописанный пример работает также    
Попробовал php_value mbstring.func_overload = 0 и 7. 
В том и другом случае ошибка не исчезла. 
TCPDF сейчас использую, но по скорости работы mPDF лучше работает.

Comment: php_value mbstring.func_overload = 0 и 7 в новом php можно установить только в конфигурации виртуального сервера php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload или в самом php.ini в htaccess и в файле скрипта их невозможно перегрузить