# генератор из html pdf

Tags: php, pdf, php7, dompdf

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, библиотеку генерации PDF файлов, которая может работать на *nix системах и "дружит" с php 7.1?

Сейчас использую DOMPDF, но есть огромная проблема: он не рендерит кириллицу на сервере. То есть на win7 он делает это, а на centos не хочет никак. Все попытки решить эту проблему не увенчались успехом, то есть вариант "починить" domPDF не подходит. Из исходных данных: просто нужен генератор PDF из HTML, то есть у меня есть HTML, который я получаю из template.html и через `strtr($html, $tpl);` подставляю нужные мне значения в шаблон.

Comment: mPDF (и ещё несколько буков)

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/237221/mpdf-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0 "Помогло php_value mbstring.func_overload = 0 "